# Is Mario or Yoshi Faster in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I have trouble choosing which character to choose in Mario Kart 8.

Is Mario faster or is Yoshi faster?

I tried both of them but is it is hard to decide!

Comment: ... what game are you even talking about

Comment: Mario kart 8 on Wii U

Comment: You should add that to the question then. As it is now, your question is unanswerable because it is impossible to have a good idea what you're asking about.

Comment: This question, specifically 'Is Yoshi faster than Mario', can be answered without opinion as characters do have stats. A chart exists on the Mario Wiki detailing this.

Answer (score 5):

If you look purely at the stats, **Mario is faster**. Take a look at the image below with the stats per character (I highlighted Mario and Yoshi's speed). Image taken from [Craveonline](http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/1258713-mario-kart-8-tier-list-every-character-ranked). If you have to take the other stats into account (for example handling), it depends on your playstyle.

[image: Character stats]

Comment: But you didn't highlight Yoshi (you marked Koopa, Lakitu and Bowser Jr.), he is also in the medium group next to Peach and Daisy. He's still a little slower though.

Comment: @Baumi thanks, I indeed highlighted the Koopa Troopa line. Fixed it :)